# How to solve a differential equation using the substitution $y=xv(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve

$x\dot y'=y(2x+y)$  given $y=xv(x)$

I have put the given equation in the form $\dot y=2(\frac{y}{x})+(\frac{y}{x})^2$ and then said that $ \dot y=F(\frac{y}{x})=F(v)$.
 The equation can then be recast as $\frac{1}{F(v)-v}dv=\frac{1}{x}dx$. I am unsure how to begin to integrate this without ending up with some horrible exponentials. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Considering the DE

$$
x y'=y(2x+y)
$$

Making $v = 1/y$ we have

$$
v'+2 v+\frac 1x = 0
$$

which is linear...

NOTE

Being linear this last DE the answer can be written as

$$
v = v_h + v_p\\
v_h'+2v_h = 0\\
v_p'+2v_p + \frac 1x = 0
$$

here $v_h = C_0 e^{-2x}$ and now substituting $y_p = C_0(x)e^{-2x}$ (Lagrange constants variation method) we get

$$
C_0'(x) = -\frac{e^{2x}}{x}\Rightarrow C_0(x) = -\int^x \frac{e^{2t}}{t}dt
$$

so

$$
v =e^{-2x} \left(C_0 -\int^x \frac{e^{2t}}{t}dt\right) = \frac 1y
$$

Comment: +1 Op thinks the equation is homogeneous but it's not so the substitution $(y=v(x)x)$ dosent work. Maybe OP meant on the LHS $x^2y'$

Comment: @Isham Yes. Otherwise the reduction $y' =2 \frac yx+(\frac yx)^2$ doesn't makes sense.

Comment: @Isham If the DE where $x^2y=y(2x+y)$ the same substitution would give $v'+\frac 2x v+\frac{1}{x^2}=0$ also linear.

Comment: Thats true but op 's equation (after substitution )$y'=F(y/x)$ seems not correct to me..maybe op made a typo..in the equation